# ENV variables in bash - why can't I access them in my Rails local setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set my Stripe Publishable and Secret Keys in my .bash_profile, and they show up fine in bash...

```
> echo $STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY
sk_test_bunchofcharacters
```

but in my stripe.rb file, they aren't getting accessed.

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
    :secret_key => ENV['STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY'],
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
byebug
```

[image]

What piece am I missing?

Everything works fine in production when I do heroku config and all that... it's just this local installation that is the trouble.

P.S. The variables don't show up in my rails console either.

Comment: How are you starting server ? Is it running under spring? If so have you reloaded

Comment: I am rebooting server just using rails s... and I have the spring gem loaded, but am not doing anything special with it.

Comment: Try stopping your server and then typing `spring stop` to stop Spring as well, and then start your server again.

Comment: 'spring stop' did the trick - thanks sir

Comment: @Jordan, can you add that as an answer so this gets marked as answered.   Please :).  I'll vote for it.

Comment: Done! <more characters...>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stopping your server and then typing `spring stop` to stop Spring as well, and then start your server again. I think environment variables only get loaded when Spring starts.